# How to combine two SQL queries with different where conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have written a query which finds the number of students of a gender in a particular class but I am unable to find a way to write a query which can do the same for both genders. I tried writing the query two times (for each gender) and then combine them using UNION but couldn't do that either.

**Query # 1**

```
SELECT MAX(Class.Class_ID) AS Class_ID,  COUNT(Enrolled_In.Reg_No) AS Male_Students
FROM Enrolled_In
INNER JOIN Class ON Enrolled_In.Class_ID = Class.Class_ID
INNER JOIN Student ON Enrolled_In.Reg_No = Student.Reg_No
WHERE Class.Class_ID = 'E-100' AND Student.Gender = 'M';
```

**Result:**

```
CLASS_ID MALE_STUDENTS
-------- -------------
E-100               2
```

**Query # 2**

```
SELECT MAX(Class.Class_ID) AS Class_ID,  COUNT(Enrolled_In.Reg_No) AS Female_Students
FROM Enrolled_In
INNER JOIN Class ON Enrolled_In.Class_ID = Class.Class_ID
INNER JOIN Student ON Enrolled_In.Reg_No = Student.Reg_No
WHERE Class.Class_ID = 'E-100' AND Student.Gender = 'F';
```

**Result:**

```
CLASS_ID FEMALE_STUDENTS 
-------- ---------------
E-100                 1
```

I want the output to be like this, preferably using a single query:

```
CLASS_ID MALE_STUDENTS FEMALE_STUDENTS
-------- ------------- --------------- 
E-100               2                1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(case when s.Gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) AS Male_Students,
       SUM(case when s.Gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) AS Female_Students
FROM Enrolled_In e
JOIN Student s ON e.Reg_No = s.Reg_No
WHERE e.Class_ID = 'E-100'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
select
  c.class_id, 
  sum(case when s.gender = 'm' then 1 else 0 end) as male_students,
  sum(case when s.gender = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) as female_students
from enrolled_in ei
join class c
on ei.class_id = c.class_id
join student s
on ei.reg_no = s.reg_no
where c.class_id = 'e-100'
group by
  c.class_id
```